# Multi Select: attaches an additional empty id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

when I want to create a new book, I need to attach it to categories. but when I try to save a new book, I get the error: "Could not find the category with < id "=". > I do not know why, but one more id attach besides those I have already attached. And this id is empty ("").
  it looks like this ("book" => {"name" => "12", "category_ids" => ["", "2", "7"], ....). Help me please.
my bookcontroler:

```
def new 
 @book = Book.new(book_params)
end

def create 
 @book = Book.new(book_params)
 @category = Category.find(id: params[:ids])
 BookCategory.create!(book: @book, category: @category)
 @book.save
end

private

def book_params
 params.require(:book).permit(:name, :author, :image, :description)
end
```

my form:

```
    <%= form_for (@book) do |f| %>
      <%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, {},{ multiple: :true } %><br>
    <% end %>
```

my error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EjAW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you have setup the associations correctly:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :book_categories
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :book_categories
  has_many :books, through: :book_categories
end

class BookCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :category
end
```

For every `has_many` association ActiveRecord creates an `_ids` setter and getter:

```
@book = Book.find(1)
@book.category_ids 
# => [1, 2, 3]
@book.category_ids = [2,4]  # will add 4 and remove 1 and 3.
```

So you don't need to manually setup the associations, just pass the `category_ids` param:

```
def new 
 @book = Book.new # don't assign params in the new method!
end

def create 
  @book = Book.new(book_params)
  if @book.save
    redirect_to @book
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

def book_params
  # category_ids: [] allows an array of scalar values
  params.require(:book)
        .permit(:name, :author, :image, :description, category_ids: [])
end
```

Your code won't work since you are using `.find` with an array param that can be nil or empty.

Also the options argument for collection_select is optional:

```
<%= form_for (@book) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_ids, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, { multiple: :true } %><br>
<% end %>
```